# Command not found: Path on iterm using zsh?

Tags: zsh, iterm2, zshrc

Whenever I start up an iTerm2 window, I get the error
        `.zshrc:1: command not found: Path`
without running anything on the command line.

My `.zshrc` file contains

```sh
export ZSH=/Users/[usr]/.oh-my-zsh
plugins=(git)
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The first line** of your `.zshrc` is :

```
Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
```

you should comment it :

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
```